# KShell regular expression comparision not working

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have the below if condition in my shell script which uses regular expressions. Basically I wanted to find out if $main contains string $pattrn.

```
main="$line1"
pattrn="$line"
if [[ $main = @($pattrn) ]];
then
echo $line>>/lawson/prod/work/errval
fi
```

Even If I have few matching values but this If condition in not returning anything.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: consider editting your question to include sample values that will be found in `$line1` and `$line` . Good luck.

Comment: it does not use regular expressions. It uses glob patterns -- read the "File Name Generation" section of your ksh man page.

Comment: You need to show what your pattern is for us to say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, though there might be a more elegant solution with sed or awk.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
variable1="ABCDEF"
variable2="CDE"

printf "variable1( %s )\n" $variable1

if( echo $variable1 | grep -q $variable2 ); then
    printf "variable2 appears in variable1\n"
fi

variable3="GHI"

if( echo $variable1 | grep -q $variable3 ); then
    printf "variable3 appears in variable1\n"
else
    printf "variable3 does not appears in variable1\n"
fi
```

Output

```
variable1( ABCDEF )
variable2 appears in variable1
variable3 does not appears in variable1
```

Explanation: You are checking the return value of the command in parenthesis to ensure that the result is equal to 0.  With the grep after the pipe, you are checking if grep found the string within the output string from the echo.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to find out if $main contains string $pattrn.
>
> ```
> if [[ $main = @($pattrn) ]]
> ```

This tests for an exactly equal match. To test if `$main` *contains* `$pattrn`, we have to specify that there may be text before and after `$pattrn`:

```
if [[ $main = @(*$pattrn*) ]]
```

By the way, since we have just one pattern, we can do without `@(…)` as well:

```
if [[ $main = *$pattrn* ]]
```